# Keras AttributeError: 'Convolution2D' object has no attribute 'set_input'

Tags: neural-network, keras, convolution

Some style transfer examples that use Keras initialize the content, style and combination images and feed them into the first layer of VGG16. 
However the Convolution2D objects do not seem to accept the set_input method.

```
input_tensor = K.concatenate([base_image,
                              style_reference_image,
                              combination_image], axis=0)

# build the VGG16 network with 3 images as input
first_layer = Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv1_1')
first_layer.set_input(input_tensor, shape)

model = Sequential()
model.add(first_layer)
model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv1_2', border_mode='same'))
model.add(pooling_func())

model.add(Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv2_1', border_mode='same'))
model.add(Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv2_2', border_mode='same'))
model.add(pooling_func())
```

Comment: `set_input` is not a valid way of setting model input - it may cause unexpected behaviour. Have you tried functional API?